# Android: Bitmap doesn't get added to ArrayList<Bitmap>

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-query, aquery

I create a Bitmap using Android Query like this:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
aq = new AQuery(HomeCategoryActivity.this);
aq.ajax(currentUrl,Bitmap.class,0,new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>(){
    @Override
    public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
            if(object != null)
            {
                bitmapArray.add(object);
            }
    }
});
```

But when I Log.d the size of the arraylist, it returns 0. The Bitmap is NOT NULL, I checked by setting it as an image resource. It simply doesn't get added to the arraylist. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Where are you performing the Log?
It sounds like AQuery is recycling the bitmap.  Try making a copy of the Bitmap and see if it still returns the same size.

Comment: You might also be logging the size before the request is done (before your callback is called).